# how much Mh/s is 15000 h/s?

Tags: ethereum

)

Question: When Genesis is writing 15000 h/s for 12000usd what is that in Mh/s?

I plan to mine Ethereum at the speed of 15000 h/s which is the fastest speed you can buy at Genesis. Then I intend to upgrade for the daily output until I reach a high output = USD per month.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: There is something SERIOUSLY wrong with that math. Mining Ethereum with 15000 h/s will take you over 1000 years to mine 1 ETH. I hope you know what you are getting yourself into.

Answer (score 3):

The M stands for "mega", meaning million.  So 1 Mh/s means one million hashes per second.  Some very simple math will tell you that 15000 h/s is the same a 0.015 Mh/s.